# Why the mutex code stops another whole go-routine?

Tags: go, mutex

```
var m *sync.RWMutex
func main() {
    m = new(sync.RWMutex)
    n := 100
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            write("WA", i)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            write("WB", i)
        }
    }()

    select {}
}
func write(tag string, i int) {
    m.Lock()
    fmt.Printf("[%s][%s%d]write start \n", tag, tag, i)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("[%s][%s%d]write end \n", tag, tag, i)
    m.Unlock()

    // time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Result in console:

> go run mutex.go
>   [WB][WB0]write start
>   [WB][WB0]write end
>   [WB][WB1]write start
>   [WB][WB1]write end
>   [WB][WB2]write start
>   [WB][WB2]write end
>   [WB][WB3]write start
>   [WB][WB3]write end
>   [WB][WB4]write start
>   [WB][WB4]write end
>   [WB][WB5]write start
>   [WB][WB5]write end
>   [WB][WB6]write start
>   [WB][WB6]write end
>   [WB][WB7]write start
>   [WB][WB7]write end
>   [WB][WB8]write start
>   [WB][WB8]write end
>   [WB][WB9]write start
>   [WB][WB9]write end
>   ...

```
> go version
go version go1.5.2 windows/amd64
```

The question is: 
why there is no chance for the go-routine of "[WA]"?
Why the mutex code stops another whole go-routine?

I know there must be a story or a theory about it.
Please give me a url to read and study.

Comment: The mutex doesn't stop another goroutine. But there are not guarantees about order in which scheduler will schedule goroutines.

Comment: For correct solutions watch Rob Pikes "Go Concurrency Patterns": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs 

Slides: https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1

Also for the guarentees go gives carefully read though: "The Go Memory 
model": https://golang.org/ref/mem

Comment: The behavior here is actually what you want. You want a CPU bound goroutine to stay on task and finish with its CPU cache hot, rather than bouncing all around.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and explanations. I think they all make sense.

Comment: As a plus, Go support preemptive schedule since v1.14 https://go.dev/doc/go1.14#runtime ,  which means, the print lines is out of order now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go uses cooperative multitasking; it doesn't use preemptive mutitasking: [Computer multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking). You need to give the scheduler an opportunity to run between locks. For example, by a call to Gosched(),

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var m *sync.RWMutex

func main() {
    m = new(sync.RWMutex)
    n := 100
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            write("WA", i)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            write("WB", i)
        }
    }()

    select {}
}

func write(tag string, i int) {
    m.Lock()
    fmt.Printf("[%s][%s%d]write start \n", tag, tag, i)
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("[%s][%s%d]write end \n", tag, tag, i)
    m.Unlock()
    runtime.Gosched()
}
```

Output:

```
[WB][WB0]write start 
[WB][WB0]write end 
[WA][WA0]write start 
[WA][WA0]write end 
[WB][WB1]write start 
[WB][WB1]write end 
[WA][WA1]write start 
[WA][WA1]write end 
[WB][WB2]write start 
[WB][WB2]write end 
[WA][WA2]write start 
[WA][WA2]write end 
[WB][WB3]write start 
[WB][WB3]write end 
[WA][WA3]write start 
[WA][WA3]write end
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is completely accurate. Go scheduler is partially preemptive, it can preempt at function calls for example. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11462 for example.

Comment: @kostya: preempt: to seize upon to the exclusion of others. A scheduler is preemptive if it seizes control from a running program without the program surrendering control.  
cooperate: to act or work with another or others. A scheduler is cooperative if it obtains control from a running program when the program surrenders control. The Go scheduler is a cooperative scheduler. Go programs surrender control explicitly or implicitly. The runtime.Gosched() function surrenders control explicitly. File I/O and other blocking operations and, in some cases, function calls surrender control implicitly.

Comment: @kostya: Austin's choice of words is unfortunate and confusing.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, it makes sense. Though I am still not sure that cooperative scheduler is a problem in this example. A call to write inserts a preemption point, but because Lock happens so fast after Unlock it is extremely unlikely that the control is given to another goroutine during this interval. This will be true in case of preeptive scheduler as well.

Answer (score 2):

This situation is called live lock.

When you call `m.Unlock()` even though two goroutines (A and B) are waiting for this lock to be released the scheduler is free to wake up any of them to proceed.

It looks like the current implementation of scheduler in Go doesn't switch to goroutine A fast to enough for it to acquire the mutex. Before this happens goroutine B re-acquires the mutex.

As you probably found out if you move `time.Sleep` call after `m.Unlock` call both A and B goroutines will be running concurrently.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

@peterSO 's answer is correct. Just to elaborate a bit on scheduling, that `for` loop is a sequential tight loop. Means that the compiled instructions from that loop, would occupy a whole thread to finish. Meanwhile other bits of low level instructions would block unless they have some schedule cycles provided by `runtime.Gosched()` or sleep, in the middle of the loop. That's why they actually have not a chance to catch on with the `sync.Mutex` (BTW both should be `sync.Mutex` at declaration and instantiation):

```
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        runtime.Gosched()
        write("WA", i)
    }
}()

go func() {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        runtime.Gosched()
        write("WB", i)
    }
}()
```

And Go scheduler is not preemptive at instruction level (like Erlang). That's why it's better to orchestrate execution path using channels.

Note: I've learnt this the hard way (not a low-level Go compiler expert). And channels provide that orchestration on Go-Routines (& those extra cycles) in a more clean manner. In other words `sync.Mutex` should be used just for supervising access to stuff; not for orchestration.